# Can I combine multiple battery packs to increase wattage?

Tags: battery-charging

I have seen a few questions similar to this, but not this same use-case.

I have several identical lithium ion battery packs that I bought primarily to recharge my laptop (and other business equipment) while travelling for conferences - they have an AC outlet that says 110v/60 hz 100 watts ([https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Universal-31200mAh-External-Notebook/dp/B07S7TK88B/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S7TK88B)). However, I recently upgraded to a beefier laptop, which overloads the battery pack. The AC adapter for the laptop says input is 100-240v ~3.5A 50-60hz.

I am a complete novice, but what I think this means is that the AC adapter requires a minimum of 100v x 3.5a = 350 watts, or 3.5x what each one of my battery packs can output on their own. My question is if there is some way to arrange 4 of these packs in a bank that would increase the amps and let my laptop charge - ideally in such a way that it doesn't look like I have a bomb in my backpack when I'm travelling.

Comment: Batteries can be combined in series or parallel, but inverters can't be. The inverter is the part that converts battery power to wall power so you can plug in your AC adapter.

Comment: depending on the laptop, it *might* be possible to find a smaller AC adapter that will also take less power from the "wall" and charge slower. Any other solution with the parts you have will require either modifying the battery packs or the charger.

Comment: Forget about it. They are AC sources and they'd be impossible to sync.  However, the laptop is overloading the pack **because the sum of a) laptop's actual power use and b) power recharging the batteries** together exceeds 100W.  If the battery were 100% full, and you were using the laptop modestly (no hard FPU or CPU, less backlight), then battery recharge draw would be 0,  and system draw might be under 100W - in that case, your packs should still work.  So try running off the packs FIRST while the battery is at 100%.